# Parse JavaScript SDK Query Not Working

Tags: parse-platform

I would like to know why could you get this error:

Error code: 102, error message: $in requires an array

I'm using Parse JavaScript SDK.

The data structure it this one:

[image]

The source code of the function is this one:

```
Parse.Cloud.define(
    "unfollow",
    function(request, response) {
        var currentUserID = request.params.currentuser;

        var followedUserID = new Array(request.params.followeduser);

        var queryRemoveFollower = new Parse.Query("userRelation");
        queryRemoveFollower.containedIn("userObjectId", followedUserID);

        queryRemoveFollower.find({
            success: function(result) {
                for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                    result[i].remove("followers", currentUserID);
                    result[i].save();
                }

                var stopFollowingQuery = new Parse.Query("userRelation");
                stopFollowingQuery.equalTo("userObjectId", currentUserID);

                stopFollowingQuery.find({
                    success: function(result) {
                        for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                            result[i].remove("following", followedUserID);
                            result[i].save();
                        }

                        response.success("Unfollow succesful!");
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        response.success("Something went wrong. Error code: " + error.code + ", error message: " + error.message);
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function(error) {
                response.success("Something went wrong. Error code: " + error.code + ", error message: " + error.message);
            }
        });
    }
);
```

I know that the data is being currently sent:

fn_unfollow.parse_data_user_id = ruWNYycty7

fn_unfollow.idOfTheUserToUnfollow = KcCNa39sgk

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is the line:

```
var followedUserID = new Array(request.params.followeduser);
```

JavaScript's Array constructor has two possible constructors:

```
new Array(element0, element1, ..., elementN)
new Array(arrayLength)
```

Since request.params.followeduser is an integer, folowedUserID is being initalized as a EMPTY array with length of request.params.followeduser.

The fix is to use either of the following (untested...):

```
var followedUserID = new Array(1, request.params.followedUser);
```

or (preferred):

```
var followedUserId = [request.params.followedUser];
```